# How to find contact matches in shared folders

Tags: vba, outlook, contacts

I am writing a macro that automatically renames emails based on information in a Contact's notes field. I'd like this macro to be able to reference Contacts in a shared contacts folder. I can't get it to work.

The problem is that I am reliant on GetContact. I don't know how to get this kind of function to refer to another Contact folder.

I'm not a programmer obviously - any help would be very appreciated. Here's the relevant part of what I've written:

```
Function AddSender(X As String)

Set myContact = thisItem.Sender.GetContact

If Not myContact Is Nothing Then

contactProperties = myContact.Body

a = InStr(contactProperties, ";")
b = InStr(contactProperties, "]")

Role = Mid(contactProperties, a + 2, b - a - 2)
MsgBox (Role)

newSubject = Role + " - " + X
thisItem.Subject = newSubject
thisItem.Save

End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

GetContact will search any Contact folder that is enabled as an Outlook Address Book (in the folder's properties dialog).  However I believe for a Contact in a shared folder that only the user's default Contacts folder is searched as only default folders can be shared.

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't mention this was for Outlook 2010. It doesn't look like you can enable a shared contact folder as an Outlook Address Book. Please let me know if I'm wrong about that.

Comment: By default, no you cannot. However there is a hack that may or may not work: https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/contacts/display-other-contacts-in-address-book/